# antlr4 grammar works with Java target, fails with Python one

Tags: java, python, antlr

I initially developed a grammar using the Java target (for TestRig support) and then ported it to Python (extends the Python3 grammar from the git hub grammar repo so needed to port actions to Python). After adding some helper print methods to both versions, and running both parsers on the same input, the Python target produces an error.

I have used the setTrace method to get a trace output and after running both, traces are identical (minor some blankline differences from the print statements). This tells me both parsers are encountering the same tokens and building the same tree... in theory. However, as mentioned the Java version finishes correctly while the Python one has a "... but expected ... " error.

Has anyone detected similar behaviour and if so, has found a workaround? Sorry that I don't post actual code but the grammas are lenghty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour was the result of a bug in the Python3 antlr grammar definition. I have added a fix[1] for the grammar definition in the antlr grammars project.

[1]https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/commit/4eb968b8d8bc11185042b2ba69f14e349bee3468